# Extending Backbone to Support Rails Style Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm looking for an approach to reduce code duplication. Currently, whenever I save a Backbone model, I always provide the following code to deserialize the Rails stock `422` response into an errors property:

```
model.save({ name: "..." }, error: function(model, response) {
  result = $.parseJSON(response.responseText)
  model.errors = result.errors
  ...
});
```

Is it possible to configure Backbone so it deserializes errors before calling my callback? I tried overriding the `sync` method but at that point the callback is wrapped in a anonymous function (and no longer accessible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ErrorHandler` model that is extended by other models requiring error parsing. The `ErrorHandler` model should listen for the "error" event (triggered by the sync function when errors occur after a request).

```
var ErrorHandler = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.on("error", this.defaultErrorHandler, this);
    },

    defaultErrorHandler: function(model, error) {
        result = $.parseJSON(response.responseText)
        model.errors = result.errors
        ...
    }

});

var OtherModel = ErrorHandler.extend({
    ...
});

var model = new OtherModel();

model.save({ name: "..." });
```